# How to inset duplicate data in flask-sqlalchemy. by avaiding SQL-ALCHEMY integrity error

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

```
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse, Api


    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data.db'
    app.secret_key = 'Thinkonce'
    api = Api(app)
    db = SQLAlchemy()


    class UserModel(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'items'
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        username = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
        email =  db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)


        def __init__(self, username, email):
            self.email = email
            self.username = username

        def json(self):
            return {"username": self.username, "email": self.email}

    @app.before_first_request
    def create_tables():
        db.create_all()

    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return "Home Page"

    class ItemList(Resource):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('username',
            type=str,
            required=True,
            help="username cannot be blank"
        )
        parser.add_argument('email',
            type=str,
            required=True,
            help="email cannot be blank"
        )
        def post(self):
            data = ItemList.parser.parse_args()
            db.session.add(UserModel(username=data["username"], email=data['email']))
            db.session.commit()
            return {"message":"User created successfully"}, 201

        def get(self):
            print(UserModel.query.all())
            return {'item':[i.json() for i in UserModel.query.all()]}, 200

    api.add_resource(ItemList, '/api')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        db.init_app(app)
        app.run(port=5000, debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

data i am inserting:

```
{
    "username":"soubhagya",
    "email":"soubhagya@gmail.com"
}
```

flask_sqlalchemy does not accept duplicate data .
is there any way to avoid this or how to insert duplicate data.
It is giving sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError

errors:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: items.email [SQL: 'INSERT INTO items (username, email) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: ('soubhagya', 'soubhagya@gmail.com')] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj) // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=style.css"
            type="text/css">
            <!-- We need to make sure this has a favicon so that the debugger does
             not by accident trigger a request to /favicon.ico which might
             change the application state. -->
            <link rel="shortcut icon"
            href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=console.png">
            <script src="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=debugger.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
          var TRACEBACK = 140039101353152,
              CONSOLE_MODE = false,
              EVALEX = true,
              EVALEX_TRUSTED = false,
              SECRET = "kTQfbKAGsVJTWQ4ihbMf";
        </script>
```

I have shared the model also.

Please have a look into this.

Question is edited and i have shared my complete code.

Now please have a look

Comment: Do you mean you want to insert two identical rows in a database table?

Comment: yes. i want duplicate datas

Comment: Hmm. Can you post your data models?

Comment: yes. i am able to post. but getting error on duplicate post

Comment: I mean, attach the code that defines your data models to your question.

Comment: question edited.

Comment: Ok. No issues with data model. So, can you add a full stack trace to your question?

Comment: I have shared the errors above.

Comment: I've answered your question. Though I don't understand why would you want to duplicate your users. Almost in every web application users should be unique. Web application should not have something to do with data backups.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to appear because flask-sqlalchemy implicitly adds unique constraint to the email field. This leaves two possible solutions.

First, explicitly remove this constraint by

```
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
```

Or by giving this column some other name.

For better understanding of constraints in SQLAlchemy, I advice to visit [its documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html).

**UPD** (Based on comments to this answer)

The error has nothing to do with SQLite or SQLAlchemy. It just says that you are trying to add non-unique value into a column where all values should be unique and you have to deal with somehow. Also, not Flask nor SQLAlchemy do not make any data migrations. This means that if you add some fields to your model or add another model to your database *scheme*, you'll need to create your database from scratch or use special tools for data migration.

Probably, all you needed was to delete old `data.db` file where this constraint existed.

Comment: That's very confusing. Can you upload full code somewhere?

Comment: Try to remove constructor from your model.

Comment: Actually i get it. it is not issue with flask. it is is issue with sqlite database. it won't accept duplicate data.it works now when i changed to mysql

Comment: I'm not sure. SQLite surely accepts non-unique data, it just can't work the way you've described. It might be some bug in SQLALchemy itself. Can you switch back to SQLite and apply my previous suggestion?